# Stored procedure not running on the same database when using different login

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to run a stored procedure on the same database using two different login users. While using the Windows authentication , I'm able to run the stored and proc and see all the data available. But while running the same stored proc using a specific user authentication, I am not able to view the data. The stored proc is running but returning 0 rows.

The  permissions for both accounts are the same.

Any suggestions on what might be the problem or how to approach in solving this issue?

Comment: What is the role specified at schema for that specific user authentication ? Could be possible that windows authentication has select/update/delete permissions as compared to that user auth and hence you see the diff in results?

Comment: Check the default database assigned to each login and/or make sure you are specifying the correct database when connecting.  Do you have this stored procedure in more than one place?  Did you by chance accidentally create a copy of it in Master?

Comment: I had that happen once and it turned out that the SP had code in it that did some user defined security.  Is that possible in this case?

Comment: How are you connecting and then calling the stored procedure? Show some actual code please...